# Running AutoCAD LT 2024 Lisp Program using Python subprocess module

Tags: python, pywin32, autocad, autocad-plugin, autocad-scripts

I'm attempting to automate the execution of a Lisp program in AutoCAD LT 2024 using Python's subprocess module. However, I'm encountering challenges, and I'm seeking guidance on the proper approach. Here's a my code:

```
import subprocess

autocad_exe_path = r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD LT 2024\acadlt.exe'
lisp_command = '(command "LINE" "0,0" "10,10")'
subprocess. Run([autocad_exe_path, '/ld', lisp_command])
```

Background:

I'm working with AutoCAD LT 2024.
I have a Lisp program that I want to run within the AutoCAD LT environment.

- I've considered using the subprocess module in Python to execute the Lisp program from the command line.
- I've researched potential command-line parameters for AutoCAD LT 2024 to run Lisp scripts

I appreciate any insights or examples that can help me navigate this process. Thank you!

Comment: What's the error? Not sure whether it's a typo but it's ***run*** (lower case ***r***).